# Passing data in background with ScreenCaptureActivity on Android

Tags: android, android-activity, screen, capture

There is a working program that transfers the screen recording from the phone to the device. The program also launches Google navigation.
The problem is that since this is a translation from the phone screen, then phones cannot be used.
When I press "Start", navigation starts and is transferred to the panel and I want to use the phone, and the transfer of navigation continues.
With the "Stop" button, I end the transfer of the screen recording.
Here are my source codes of the program, can you look at them and tell me how to solve this problem?

[Navi](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XXa7LBmjXiwFdZBJ8xxftRE_mxH7RGFx/view?usp=sharing)

I am not a professional in java. I used the source code on the internet, but there is little information

Comment: Please do a [mre] instead of give all your code with external file

Comment: I would like to, but I'm not that strong in Java and if I remove something, then it may not work at all, but I'll try

Comment: Try to make a minimal example can help you to find where the issue come from exactly

Answer (score 0):

your code above isn't reachable : We need an specific access.

Comment: I updated access

Comment: Thanks. So if I understood, you wanna cast your phone screen, and keep the interactions possible ?

Comment: Yes. You are right